# React-native-navigation hide navigation bar on login screen?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using the react-native-navigation in my react-native application for navigation. I wanted to hide navigation bar on first screen 
I tried

```
{ navBarHidden: true}
```

The complete code for navigation is:

```
 Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
        label: "Login",
        screen: "LoginComponent",
        icon: require('./asset/menu.png'),
        title: "Login",
      }, 
      navigationBarStyle : {navBarHidden: true },
      passProps: {},
      animationType: 'slide-down'
  });
```

Not showing any error and still can  see the navbar on my login screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed

```
 Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
        label: "Login",
        screen: "LoginComponent",
        icon: require('./asset/menu.png'),
        title: "Login",
      }, 
      navigationBarStyle : {navBarHidden: true },
      passProps: {},
      animationType: 'slide-down'
  });
```

to

```
   Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
        screen: {
         label: "Login",
        screen: "LoginComponent",
        icon: require('./asset/menu.png'),
        title: "Login",
       navigationBarStyle : {navBarHidden: true },
      }, 
      passProps: {},
      animationType: 'slide-down'
  });
```

And it works like as charm.

Answer (score 3):

In React-native-navigation V2 to disable navigation bar : 
    topBar: {  visible: false }

```
Navigation.setRoot({
      root: {
        stack: {
          id: "App",
          children: [
            {
              component: {
                name: "rci.Login",
                options: {
                  topBar: {
                    visible: false
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles are declared in [navigatorStyle](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/styling-the-navigator) which can be declared statically in a screen or dynamically when pushing a screen or calling `startSingleScreenApp`

Answer (score 0):

On the new version of react-native-navigator (2.0) you have to add the param on navigatorStyle instead of navigationBarStyle.

```
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
  screen: {
    label: "Login",
    screen: "LoginComponent",
    icon: require('./asset/menu.png'),
    title: "Login",
    navigatorStyle: { navBarHidden: true }
  }, 
  passProps: {},
  animationType: 'slide-down'
});
```

That will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

> This is for reactnavigation@v2.14

```
{
   headerMode: 'none',
   navigationOptions: {
     headerVisible: false,
   }
 }
```

> Full Code

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
   Login: { screen: Login},
   Signup: { screen: Signup},
   ForgotPassword: { screen: ForgotPassword},
 }, 
 {
   headerMode: 'none',
   navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
   }
 }
)
```

Comment: His question is about react-native-navigation, not react-navigation.